# Microsoft SSAS OLAP Connection from Java Code

Tags: java, ssas, olap, olap-cube, olap4j

I am new to the concept of OLAP DB.
Please excuse me if I missed out something in the Connection String.
I am trying to connect to connect to Microsoft Analysis Server(which is in different Domain) from my System.
While Connecting I am getting below Error.

Can you please let me know, what am I doing wrong?
I have executed the Steps Mentioned in :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx

and referred to the below link for connection to the Cube:
http://www.matthewgodding.com/articles/2010/2/27/getting-data-from-sql-analysis-services-using-java-and-olap4.html

After connecting to the CUbe, I need to execute MDX Query.

Please find the snippet of the code I am using:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
      Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
      final Connection connection = DriverManager
     .getConnection("jdbc:xmla:Server=http://Remote_Server_IPAddress/OLAP/msmdpump.dll;"
                    + "Catalog=MyCatalog;"
                    + "User='Domian\\Username';"   \\ This is the Username to login to the Server
                    + "Password='Password';"   \\ This is the Password to login to the Server
                    + "Cube=Cube;");      \\This is the Cube Name
```

I get the below Exception when I execute the program:

```
  Exception:

        java.lang.RuntimeException: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:96)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.size(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:116)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getOlapDatabase(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:451)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.getDatabase(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:444)
    at org.sid.practise.CheckConnection.main(CheckConnection.java:79)
Caused by: org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaHelper.createException(XmlaHelper.java:43)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:878)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:137)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getMetadata(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:67)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProperties(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:1044)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.makeConnectionPropertyList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:324)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.generateRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:1037)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.populateList(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:849)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.populateList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:136)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.DeferredNamedListImpl.getList(DeferredNamedListImpl.java:90)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jProxyException: This proxy encountered an exception while processing the query.
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jAbstractHttpProxy.java:181)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.get(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:42)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jConnection.executeMetadataRequest(XmlaOlap4jConnection.java:876)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.proxy.XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.getResponse(XmlaOlap4jHttpProxy.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what went wrong for you. Few things you could do,

1. Don't specify cube in connection. This is not listed as property in XMLA [driver](http://www.olap4j.org/api/org/olap4j/driver/xmla/XmlaOlap4jDriver.Property.html).
2. You can install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see what's going on with the requests.
3. Not sure if single quotes are needed in user name and password.